# Marionette trigger method and listenTo

Tags: backbone.js, triggers, marionette

I have two ItemViews.

The first view should trigger an event, and the second view should listen for the trigger.  How should I go about it?

Here's what I have so far:

```
  Branch.RecipeView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    triggers: {
      'change': 'recipe:selected'
    }
  });
```

And then the second View is as follows:

```
  Branch.MetaDataView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: _.template(
      '<div id="branchImgSrc">' +
       '</div>' 
    ),
  initialize: function () {
    this.on('recipe:selected', function () {
       console.log('selected');
    });
  }
});
```

I instantiate both views and add them to the layout, but the event in ItemView one never triggers the recipe:selected in ItemView number 2.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: try using this.listenTo(Branch.RecipeView, 'recipe:selected', function () {
       console.log('selected');
    });

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends on whether or not you want `Branch.MetaDataView` to store a reference to `Branch.RecipeView`, as opposed to using some external mechanism for the event messaging.

1. If you don't mind referencing `Branch.RecipeView` you can get what you want with [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo):

   ```
   recipeView = new Branch.RecipeView();

   Branch.MetaDataView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
     template: _.template(
       '<div id="branchImgSrc">' +
        '</div>' 
     ),
     initialize: function () {
       this.listenTo(recipeView, 'recipe:selected', function () {
         console.log('selected');
       });
     }
   });
   ```
2. If you don't want to reference one view from the other directly, then you can use some other mechanism for carrying your `'recipe:selected'` event.  This could be the DOM, or this could be some kind of messaging-bus object (something like [Backbone.Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio) or even just `_.extend({}, Backbone.Events);`).

   Going through the DOM might make sense if your `Branch.RecipeView` is a child/descendent of `Branch.MetaDataView`'s `el`, as then you would get to use event bubbling as your message passing mechanism.  To do so would require triggering an event on `Branch.RecipeView`'s `$el` and then creating a [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) listener and callback on `Branch.MetaDataView` (and don't forget to remove the listener when destroying the view!).

   If you want to use a messaging object (which is definitely the best approach if you aren't emitting the event from a child/descendent view) just take a look at the Backbone.Radio readme, particuarly the [`Backbone.Events`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio/blob/master/README.md#backboneevents) section for the simplest example:

   ```
   // Create a message bus
   var myBus = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

   // Listen in on the message bus
   this.listenTo(myBus, 'some:event', myCallback);

   // Trigger an event on the bus
   myBus.trigger('some:event');
   ```